# How can I change a string Time = 2:30 PM into TimeSpan = 14:00

Tags: c#, time

I have a string strTimeofDay = "2:30 PM-3:00 PM".  I need to convert that into 2 strings using military time.

I have tried this code:

```
if (Results.TimeOfDay != "-" || Results.TimeOfDay != null)
                    {
                        string strTimeofDay = Convert.ToString(Results.TimeOfDay);
                        if (strTimeofDay != null)
                        {
                            string[] times = strTimeofDay.Split('-');
                            string time1 = times[0];
                            RadTimePicker1.SelectedTime = ParseTime(time1);
                            string time2 = times[1];
                            RadTimePicker2.SelectedTime = ParseTime(time2);
                        }
                    }
static public TimeSpan ParseTime(string input)
    {
        string trimed = input.Trim();
        TimeSpan output;
       var ok = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(trimed, @"hh\:mm\:tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out output);
        return output;
    }
```

But the output comes out as false.  What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you doing `Convert.ToString(Result.TimeOfDay)`? I'd assume it's already a string based on the `Result.TimeOfDay != "-"`.

Comment: To handle the AM/PM you'll need to parse them as `DateTime` and then get the `TimeOfDay`

Comment: Also your question says _" I need to convert that into 2 strings"_ and you're actually converting it to timespans. What is the actual question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a string in the format "2:30 PM" into the string "14:00" is as easy as parsing it using one format, and outputting it to a different one

```
var input = "2:30PM";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input,"h:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);
var output = dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BRl2du

If you wanted that as a `TimeSpan` it would simply be `dt.TimeOfDay`.